# ModuleNotFoundError Despite Installing with pip

Tags: macos, module, python-3.8, modulenotfounderror

mac os Catalina, python3.8.2

Hey All,

I know there are similar questions about this, but they didn't seem to help me.  I installed a module (quandl) using pip3.8 install. Then I try to import quandl in a .py file and get a ModuleNotFoundError.  I do have multiple versions of python installed, can't figure out how to get rid of them safely, hence why I used pip3.8 install to make sure it points to the write place.  Still no dice.  I am not using a venv.

From the terminal, this is the pip3.8 install path: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
From the .py file via VScode, I am interpreting using: /usr/local/bin/python3.8

Can someone educate me on what I am doing wrong?

I was previously interpreting from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3, but I noticed pip was not installing there.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of your VSCode window, there's an orange status bar.  Starting at the far left, you'll see your git repo info, the git status, and then the Python environment you're using.  If you click that, VSCode will slide in a modal dialog window that'll let you choose your python environment -- my VSCode defaulted to `/usr/bin/python3`, but my pip3 (and python3) are in `/usr/local/bin`.  Once I picked the correct interpreter, I stopped getting the `ModuleNotFoundError`